# Memory Usage on Fatal Error, should I Try Catch every line?

Tags: php, apache, memory

What happens exactly on a PHP fatal error regarding memory usage and object destruction? Does memory automatically get freed on a fatal error?

I really would like to know more about the subject, and couldn't find it in the PHP manual.

Should I worry about Try{}catch{} my functions so I can destruct my objects in the catch{} or does it happen automatically ? Is it instant ?

**Added Example:**

```
$objectOne = new stdClass();
$objectOne->statement = "Hello";

$objectTwo = new stdClass();
randomFunctionThatShouldCauseAnError();
$objectTwo->statement = "Error before this";
```

In the above axample, will $objectOne be freed automatically on the error caused by `randomFunctionThatShouldCauseAnError` ? or I should do the following:

```
$objectOne = new stdClass();
$objectOne->statement = "Hello";

$objectTwo = new stdClass();
try{
    randomFunctionThatShouldCauseAnError();
}catch (Error $e){
    $objectOne = null;
    $objectTwo = null;
}
$objectTwo->statement = "Error before this";
```

Sorry for the spam of questions, but I've been struggling with this for a while now, and I would like to know how to handle memory in case of a fatal error in my code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your program is terminated in any way, including fatal errors, the entire thing is dumped from memory. The *operating system* will free the memory of any crashed application.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the quick reply! You think you can lead me to an article or documentation where I can read more about it ? It's just that I need a kind of official reference, please don't take any offence.

Comment: Let's put it this way: *try actually catching a fatal error.* You can't. Any *fatal error* will instantly kill your program, and none more of your code will execute. Especially when the program is running out of memory, it simply cannot execute any more code (because it would have to use some more memory to do so)…

Comment: @deceze register_shutdown_function() can't catch a fatal error ? I should clear the memory there if so ?

Comment: Since a shutdown function may try to allocate new memory if it's doing anything useful (in fact, even just calling that shutdown function will require some more memory to be allocated), that simply cannot happen if you're *out of memory.*

Comment: @deceze I'd like to thank you for your dedication and answers, and please excuse me for spamming you with questions ^.^ One last, if I was not out of memory and I really want to narrow my memory usage, the best I could, so I don't get out of memory, should I destroy created objects on fatal error ? Or PHP will do it for me ?

Comment: Again, *fatal errors* kill the entire script (that's why they're called **fatal**). The operating system will clean all the memory then, and there's nothing you can do on a **fatal** error because your script has **fatally** died already.

Comment: @deceze Got it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

> Should I worry about Try{}catch{} my functions so I can destruct my objects in the catch{} or does it happen automatically ? Is it instant ?

You should catch the exceptions if you want to keep the code running, otherwise you can easily have unexpected behavior from your program. 
If you do not catch an exception, a fatal error can be thrown and stop your code execution and, consequently, the OS will dump anything from memory.

Also you should take care not to expose sensitive information (i.e. An PDOException can throw your SQL password to user's screen).
Try this:

```
<?php
class Test {
    public $param;

    public function canThrowAnError() {
        $this->param = "Changed right before the exception";
        if (true) {
            throw new \Exception("Message", 10023);
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
$test = new Test();
$test->param = "Yay, it works still...";
try {
    $test->canThrowAnError();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Do something. Log, inform the user..
}
echo $test-param;
```

If you catch the exception the code will go on and everything will be as right before the exception. The following will result in:

```
"Changed right before the exception"
```

You should treat the error accordingly so you don't have unexpected behavior.

Comment: You only catch an exception *if you know what to do with it.* Reflexively catching every possible exception is nonsense. Unless you have a clear plan for `// Do something.`, don't catch it. For example, what if it's a `PDOException` about a syntax error in the query, or the database having died? What do you do about those errors at runtime? Nothing. The only thing you *can* do is die and have a programmer or sysadmin fix the problems. So let the exception kill the program.

Comment: I think it is different to let the PHP interpreter kill the program with a fatal error rather than catching the exception yourself. You can display a nice custom error code so your client can address you to the error faster. Plus, the fatal error usually results in a malformed result (web app or script not logging errors).
I agree that you have to know what to do, but at last you can just `die()` it.

Comment: That's the job of the web server. During development, you want to see exceptions in all their gory detail. In production, you silence errors with `display_error = false` in php.ini, and you configure the web server to put up a nice 5xx page in case of PHP producing any errors. You don't need to burden your code with that kind of thing. Keep it simple.

Comment: Agree with you on that. Keeping it simple is better. I edited my answer because I don't think I have expressed myself clearly.